# Macbook Pro 2006 Snow Leopard Screen Problem

Tags: snow-leopard

After changing my broken screen, i setup 10.6.8 to my macbook. But screen divided 4 part, what can be solution,? please help me. this is how its looking
[image: Four images instead of 1?!]

Comment: still waiting for help